# What's the usage of "only" here?

Tags: grammar, meaning

[image]

> She's just like a guy I know. Only, he didn't get a small practice bike He bought a fucking Harley-Davidson, despite having never rode a bike.

Is it actually like "Not only did he get a small practice bike..."?

Comment: The full stop after ***know*** is erroneous / misleading. The entire text from that point on is a "caveat" to the initial assertion, where ***only*** means ***except*** (there was this one detail about her that ***wasn't*** like the guy the writer knew). So if the other guy bough a H-D as his first bike, and "she" was somehow *different", I suppose the implication is this *current* (female) biker has in fact got herself a practice bike to start with. Odd phrasing though, to say the least.

Comment: Where did you get this text from? Are you ***sure*** you haven't mixed up some ***he's*** and ***she's**?*

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica It's not a mixed sentence. I added the picture.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica This one is an old picture so I don't remember it well, but "she" is a character in a show and bought a very expensive bike. And the "guy" seems to be a real person.

Comment: I understand that now. Presumably this "Hijiri" is typically depicted riding a "practice bike" rather than a "mean machine" such as a Harley-Davidson.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using "Not only" instead of "only" would give the sentence a very different meaning.

If it were "Not only", it would mean that he got both a small practice bike AND a fucking Harley-Davidson.

"Only" by itself is used to distinguish and highlight the contrast between the two characters - one got a small practice bike, and one got a fucking Harley. Here it is used in the same way as "except" would be.

It is using irony to make a point - the author is saying they are so similar, except in this one specific and very important way they are very different.

Comment: Using ***not only*** would just give you a syntactically invalid result, with no obvious "intended meaning".

Comment: I was referring to the alternative version provided by the asker: "Not only did he get a small practice bike..." which would work fine syntactically but completely change the meaning.

Comment: Ah, right. I see that now. But I'll leave my first comment because others might make the same mistake as me (unless you edit your answer text to include that clarification, in which case all these comments would become redundant anyway).

Comment: @kettle_hands Just a heads up. To avoid false alarms of profanity by system bots, which can cause problems for you, do not quote profanity that appears in pictures. If it's needed for the context of the message **bleep** it out. (F*******G)

Answer (score 1):

Those two sentences are saying different things.

> Not only did he get a small practice bike...

Means he did get a small practice bike... [and something else about that].

> Only, he didn't get a small practice bike He bought a fucking
>   Harley-Davidson, despite having never rode a bike.

Means he didn't buy a small practice bike, he bought a Harley instead.

Also, rode is not the past participle of *to ride*. I would write "never having ridden a bike".

Comment: To avoid false alarms from system bots, you should bleep out profanity even if it is quoted by the source.

Answer (score 1):

The “only” in this sentence can mean “but”. It’s trying to explain how she’s like the guy, but with one difference. Only can be replaced with “but” when there is just one thing that is being talked about.

Answer (score 1):

> She's just like a guy I know. **Not only** did he get a small practice bike, he bought a fucking Harley-Davidson, despite having never rode a bike.

This means he bought a small practice bike (which the author thinks was a bad idea) and he also bought a Harley-Davidson (which the author thinks is an even worse idea).

> She's just like a guy I know. **Only**, he didn't get a small practice bike. He bought a fucking Harley-Davidson, despite having never rode a bike.

This means **she** bought a small practice bike, **unlike him** (the guy), who bought a Harley-Davidson (which the author thinks was a bad idea).

Here "only" means "except" or "but".

From Oxford Learner's Dictionaries:

> [**only**](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/only_3) *conjunction*
>
> (*informal*)
>
> ​except that; but
>
> - *I'd love to come, only I have to work.*
> - *It tastes like chicken, only stronger.*

---

P.S. "rode" should be "ridden"

Comment: Thank you so much!